# C++ Virtual Method

Tags: c++

If I create a struct:

```
struct joinpoint_exception: exception
{

   virtual const char* what () const throw ();
};
```

What does `what () const throw ()` means in this context?

Comment: <pedantic>In C++ they're not "method"s, they're "member functions". </pedantic>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`what` is a virtual member function returning a pointer to constant `char` which is itself constant and throws nothing.

```
virtual const char* what () const throw ();
|-----| <- virtual member function
        |---------| <- returning a pointer to constant chars
                    |-----| <- named what
                            |---| <- which is constant
                                  |-------| <- which does not throw
```

(Technically the function can still throw, but if it does, it goes directly to `std::unexpected`, which defaults to calling `std::terminate`)

Answer (score 5):

`what` is name of the method

`const` means that the method does not alter any internal data unless its `mutable`

`throw ()` means that the method should not throw an exception, if it does `std::unexpected` is thrown instead

Comment: For `const`, that is not correct. The method can still modify `mutable` members. For `throw`, that is also not correct. The function can still throw, though any attempt to do so calls `std::unexpected`.

Comment: @Billy:  thanks for the clarification.  I never use mutalbe, if a method is const, its const for me :-)  std::unexpected was new to me

Answer (score 3):

It means that `what()` is `const` (i.e. it won't modify the logical state of the object) and that it doesn't throw any exceptions (as indicated by `throw()`).